# DEM 3D problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d, qgis2threejs

I am facing a problem to [image] make this DEM 3D problem in qgis2threejs plugin scene. Does anyone have solution on it?

Comment: Can you post some more information? Like a print screen of the settings you used? Also, it would be good if you could share your data, or a small sample. It's very difficult to help you with so little information.

Comment: It looks like your X/Y and Z units are different. Vertical exaggeration of 1.0e-5 might help.

Comment: @Nikos plz let me know what kind of data you need.

Comment: @Vince if i keep my vertical exaggeration 0.0 then it's work ok,but when i make it 0.1 or any other value it's become like that.

Comment: @AbdullahMaroof as I said, I just used a DEM (CRS in meters) and the rest are shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I assume, the CRS which set for the map of your **QGIS-project itself** is WGS 84 EPSG:4326 (Decimal Degrees).
Change it to metric CRS, for example, to WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) or WGS 84 /UTM with the zone corresponding to the location of your area.

Comment: nop my PCS is web merkater

Comment: sorry for being late response , i had solved the problem and yes it was about CRS

Comment: Web Mercator is absolutely *awful* for the XY with Z, since both the X and Y distances are variable.

Answer (score 1):

qgis3threejs treats the canvas outside the DEM as having elevation 0. If your DEM is well above sea-level, you get the effect you're seeing. Look at this [issue on the qgis2threejs repository](https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs/issues/167) for hints on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `New 3D Map View` in `QGIS` 3.22.12 I had no issue making the DEM looking 3D. DEM's CRS was in meters and the settings I used are showing below:
[image: 3d map view]

You can access the `3D Map View` by selecting View -> New 3D Map View
[image: access 3d view]

My study area is well above the sea surface but I didn't have issues with the visualization.

Answer (score 0):

OPs problem was CRS, but I've had an identical looking problem with different origin/solution:

Apparently there were points with no data in the raster. Those are treated as 0 values by threeJS, with my other points being up to 2500m in altitude it gave an extreme stretch.

It was resolved by:
Raster>Analysis> Fill nodata - thereafter I had no more such issues.